Why can remark work independently from unified?
In my understanding, unified is an interface for processing content with syntax trees, and remark is a set of plugins. That means one must use unified and attach plugins to it. For example:
import rehypeSanitize from 'rehype-sanitize'
import rehypeStringify from 'rehype-stringify'
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
import remarkRehype from 'remark-rehype'
import {unified} from 'unified'

const file = await unified()
  .use(remarkParse)
  .use(remarkRehype)
  .use(rehypeSanitize)
  .use(rehypeStringify)
  .process('# Hello, Neptune!')

console.log(String(file))

But this page lists examples that use remark directly. E.g.:
import {remark} from 'remark'
import remarkPresetLintConsistent from 'remark-preset-lint-consistent'
import remarkPresetLintRecommended from 'remark-preset-lint-recommended'
import {reporter} from 'vfile-reporter'

const file = await remark()
  .use(remarkPresetLintConsistent)
  .use(remarkPresetLintRecommended)
  .process('1) Hello, _Jupiter_ and *Neptune*!')

console.error(reporter(file))

I don't understand why it can work like that. Is it that remark is a version (or fork) of unified that is more focused on something?


Why can remark work independently from unified?

It doesn't work independently. remark uses unified as dependency.
https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/blob/remark-stringify%4011.0.0/packages/remark/package.json#L43
export const remark = unified().use(remarkParse).use(remarkStringify).freeze()

https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/blob/remark-stringify%4011.0.0/packages/remark/index.js#L10
const file = await remark()
  .use(remarkPresetLintConsistent)
  .use(remarkPresetLintRecommended)
  .process('1) Hello, _Jupiter_ and *Neptune*!')

is similar to
const file = await unified()
  .use(remarkParse)
  .use(remarkStringify)
  .use(remarkPresetLintConsistent)
  .use(remarkPresetLintRecommended)
  .process('1) Hello, _Jupiter_ and *Neptune*!')

Calling remark() is only a short-cut to configure unified with remarkParse and remarkStringify.

With freeze at the end, does this mean remark is a processor? So is it correct that plugins can either attach to processor or the interface?

@Ooker Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. If you have a new question. Post a new question. You should elaborate what exactly is unclear in the documentation. What do you mean with "interface"? unified() returns a processor.
